# Read a local project file when a page is loaded

Tags: javascript

I am trying to read a project file that will be updated(occasionally) by me and my website will read it dynamically upon the loading of the page, will i have to build a server for this or can javascript handle it?

If so, could you share code that could achieve this.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: More details needed. What is the format of the file? You say "local", but local to what? The website, the client, what?

Comment: local to the website, a plaintext file

Comment: Will the solution I presented work in your application?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be how can one:

1. read a plaintext file stored on the website's local directory
2. use the contents of the file to modify a web page's content

This could be handled with JavaScript on the server side, but only if the server is configured to run JavaScript (like a node.js server).

Since the original question reads "will i have to build a server for this", it's probably likely that this is a vanilla server like Apache.

Most Apache servers are configured to run PHP code, so PHP is probably the simplest solution for grabbing the plaintext file.

Code below will load the contents of a plaintext file on the server into a JavaScript string, which then can be acted upon in the browser with JavaScript.

This code would go inside a `<script>` element in the HTML file:

```js
function actUponProjectFile () {

  // read project file on server using PHP, and store into JavaScript
  // constant `projectFileString`
  const projectFileString = `<?php
    $pfText = file_get_contents('./my_project_file.txt');
    echo $pfText; ?>`;

  // insert code to act upon the `projectFileString` here
}

// run `actUponProjectFile()` after the window loads
window.onload = () => {
  actUponProjectFile();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Save your data in a Javascript file and include it in your html

```
// data.js 
const data = [
  {
    type: 'airtime',
    price: 20,
    size: '5GB',
  },
  {
    type: 'electricity',
    price: 10,
    size: '40mw',
  },
];
```

Then include the file in your html file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="data.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `nginx` to share static files and use `fetch` request in `js` to get this file from server. If you have only static files you don't need to use server, `nginx` will be enough for you.